# How to make an accordion completely transparent

Tags: jquery

How to make an accordion completely transparent, In Css

I tried:

[css]

```
 #accordion {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 1000px;
height: 400px;
  background-image: transparent;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#888;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px lightgray,
            1px 1px 3px darkgray;
}
```

[html]

```
<div id="accordion" >
All the information goes here!
</div>
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

PS: If you can't help stop thumbing me down.

Comment: People are voting you down, because this question is missing a lot of information. First off, this is only partial CSS (only the declaration part).  You are missing a selector. Assuming you are using a selector in your code, please update your question with it. Secondly, without seeing your HTML, we can't help you. Please post both parts (complete CSS and HTML) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Steve okay thanks I didn't know why I was getting thumbed down. Please see my updated question.

Comment: What do you mean by "transparent"? Should you still be able to see the text inside it?

Comment: @ssorallen it should adapt the background color.

Comment: Like the columm header and content should all be see thru. Like the windows 7 start bar?

Answer (score 0):

To make an element in CSS completely transparent, I would do

```
visibility: hidden;
```

This, as opposed to `display: none`, still makes the div tag take up space. It's just not rendered.

Please let me know if this is not what you had in mind.

Comment: won't this hide the text?

Comment: I see. You didn't specify you wanted the text to still be visible. I'm assuming you are trying to override another CSS specification then, so what about `background-image: none`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were trying to get rid of a background-image. The default for `background-image` is `none`. Try these two styles:

```
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
```